# vb.net Async I just don't get it

Tags: vb.net, async-await

```vb
Public Function PiesTableTest(compairFile As String, version1 As String, Optional silent As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Dim dpgs As New frmDetailProgress
    Dim retturn As Boolean

    PiesThreadedTableTest(compairFile, version1, silent, dpgs)
End Function

Async Function PiesThreadedTableTest(compairFile As String, version1 As String, silent As Boolean, dpgs As frmDetailProgress) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim ctl() As xmlControlAry
    Dim xmlDoc As XElement
    Dim xmlNodes As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    Dim notfound(0) As String

    version = version1

    nodeErrors = False
    If Not silent Then
        dpgs.lblTital.Text = "Pies Configuration Check"
        dpgs.add("Pies Version = " & version)
        dpgs.add("Loading Config Data....")
        dpgs.Show()
    End If

    ' load configuration data
    GetPiesControl(ctl, version)
    ' load test xml file
    xmlDoc = XElement.Load(compairFile)
    xmlNodes = xmlDoc.Elements()
    For Each ele As XElement In xmlNodes
        NodeDrill("", ele, ctl, dpgs, notfound, silent)
    Next
    If nodeErrors And Not silent Then
        dpgs.add("Testing done with Errors!!!", "R")
    Else
        dpgs.add("Testing Done NO ERRORS!", "G")
    End If
    Application.DoEvents()
    If silent Then
        dpgs.Dispose()
    End If

    'PiesThreadedTableTest = Not nodeErrors
    If nodeErrors Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

I am trying to understand multi threading. frmDetailProgress is a "please wait " kind of form. and i have a animated gif on it. Plus it has a check box to close automatically after completion. Well the form is frozen till the process is done. I am trying to get the piesthreadedtabletest to run in another thread. I have read allot on this but i just don't understand the concept. I don't understand the await function enough to make this work. i get that await is designed to stop processing until something happens. But i want that form freed up to work. I get an error saying that the function will run synchronously unless i have an await - Why?

Comment: Await and Async work TOGETHER.  You would have to `await PiesThreadedTableTest(...)`, but you shouldn't be accessing `dpgs` from within your async task like that.  When you want to update the form, you need to use [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Invoke_System_Delegate_) to get back on the UI thread.

Comment: that syntax shows an error.  Await PiesThreadedTableTest(compairFile, version1, silent, dpgs)

Comment: can you show me the syntax to access the form?

Comment: can you point me to a link with good explanation of this concept. All my searches turn up articles that are difficult to grasp, i guess i need a remedial course.

Comment: Can you show the top of the function in your post?...it's cut off.

Comment: Public Function PiesTableTest(compairFile As String, version1 As String, silent As Boolean, dpgs As frmDetailProgress) As boolean

Comment: disregard the one above i was trying different things here is the original.  Public Function PiesTableTest(compairFile As String, version1 As String, Optional silent As Boolean) As Boolean

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. If relevant information is missing, don't provide it in a comment. Edit the question to make it complete.

Comment: I mean the function above that one.  Look at your post.  It has an `End Function` near the top, with some code above, but not the beginning of that function.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I think it was an error in the formatting.  You should be able to see it once my edit goes through.

Comment: `Async` doesn't do anything on its own, and it certainly doesn't magically make a routine work the way you want it to work.  All it does is allow using `Await`.  Even then, you need to have something to `Await`.  In your case, it looks like your XML processing doesn't have an existing asynchronous interface, so you'd probably want to turn it into a task using `Task.Run`; you can `Await` the result of `Task.Run` (and ditch the `DoEvents` which is superfluous with the use of `Await`) and have a responsive UI while processing proceeds.

Comment: Check out the following  [code samples](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/async-basics-vb)  which may help understanding asynchronous operations but note none of them address your current task.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. Karen, i will look at the code examples and try to understand the concept. Thanks.

Comment: Never ever call `Application.DoEvents()`. It is evil incarnate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. It was a lack of understanding and i probably still need to learn more. I hope this will help someone in the future.

i created a class to call functions in the other class running in the second thread.

```
imports system.threading

public sub callThreadedProcedure()
dim tp as system.threading.thread ' this will be for the object running in the other thread

dim objectToRun as myclass ' this is the object you want to run in the thread

'this gets the object and puts it into the new thread
tp = new thread(sub() objectToRun.FunctionToRun(<put your parameters here if any>))


' start execution of the object in a new thread. 
tp.start()
' that will get it to run in a separate thread. It works, there might be a better way
' and might not work in all situations, but for now it fixed my problem.

end sub
```

if you are trying to run functions in the original thread you need to pass a
reference to that object to the one in the second thread. you must then use invoke to run a function or sub from the second thread.

```
Invoke(sub() obj.function(<parameters>))
```

thanks Idle_mind invoked worked like it should.
I appreciate all that helped me along.